# Having more than 1 navigation controller in an app

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad

I've been requested to mock up an app with the following design.

[image]

The large gray box is the main view area. (UIView)

The 2 pink squares are buttons. They are almost like tabs of a tabbar in how they should function.

What I am struggling to achieve is to get 2 UINavigationbars/Controllers to appear in the UIView(large gray box) when a button is pressed. Not at the same time of course, but which ever Navbar/Controller/View that is shown is dependent on what button was selected.

I can make a UIViewControllers view appear there ok by doing the following

```
    TabViewOne * vcTab = [[TabViewOne alloc] initWithNibName:@"TabViewOne" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
[self.mainView addSubview:vcTab.view];
```

That makes the view of TabViewOne appear in my mainView area (gray box).

What I would actually like to happen is that I can get my view to appear here but with a navbar and all the functionality that it brings. I will eventually just hide the nav bar but use its functionality to move up and down the view stack.

This is what I tried to get it working but the view stays blank when I try this :

```
    TabViewOne * vcTab = [[TabViewOne alloc] initWithNibName:@"TabViewOne" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
UINavigationController * navVC = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vcTab];
[[navVC navigationBar] setHidden:YES];

[self.mainView addSubview:navVC.view];
```

Could somebody please advise me how to do this properly?

Many Thanks,
-Code

Comment: Maybe you need [Container View Controllers](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/AboutViewControllers/AboutViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH112-SW17) ?

Comment: set nav controller's frame 'navVC.view.frame = self.mainView.bounds;'

Comment: also, dont create controllers every time just create them at start and show them on top using 'bringSubViewToFront' method on button click. If you want to start with the first view controller in nav stack every time, just call 'popToRootViewController' every time before bringing nav controller's view to front.

Comment: I agree containment might be the way to go. But is there a reason you can't present both of these navigationControllers modally which should be easy? Failing that put your mainView in a navigationController and push into that - if you want you can hide the navigationBar when you don't want to to see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve your requirement from a small trick. You can implement a tab bar controller there. In tab bar controllers each tab can be run inside a separate navigation controller. In the root view controller of both the tab items you have to have that 2 button design. If you use a generic view and add it as a subview you can easily reuse it. Next thing is it will appear the tab bar at the bottom of the view as you have a tab bar controller there. You can hide it simply by making its frame rectangle to a non visible position. After that your tab selection should be done manually based on the users button click.